# PHPUnit Data Provider error: ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function, 0 passed in, and exactly 2 expected

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm trying to use a Data Provider in my PHP test. I'm getting this error:

> There was 1 error:
>
> 1. TaskRunnerTest::testGetCountryIdByName ArgumentCountError: Too few
>    arguments to function TaskRunnerTest::testGetCountryIdByName(), 0
>    passed in
>    /app/cmd-app/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php on line
>    1182 and exactly 2 expected

Here is my test:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

final class TaskRunnerTest extends TestCase
{
    ...
    
    #[DataProvider('apiCountryNamesProvider')]
    public function testGetCountryIdByName(string $apiCountryName, string $dbCountryName): void 
    {
        // Configure the stub.
        $this->dbStub->expects($this->once())
            ->method('getCountryIdByName')
            ->with($this->equalTo($dbCountryName));
        
        // test 
        $this->taskRunner->getCountryIdByName($apiCountryName);
    }

    ...

    public static function apiCountryNamesProvider(): array
    {
        return [
            ["Saudi-Arabia", "Saudi Arabia"],
        ];
    }

}
```

I'm using PHPUnit version 11 (packages.lock):

```
{
    "name": "phpunit/phpunit",
    "version": "11.0.4",
    ...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you just missing a use statement for the attribute? `use PHPUnit\Framework\Attributes\DataProvider;`

Comment: Yep! That was it, thanks. I haven't used PHP/PHPUnit in a while, so trying to familiarise myself with attributes rather that doc-comments.